# Xenroll library. Certificate request in WinXP with KeyUsage.

Tags: c#, windows-xp, x509certificate

I have WinXP client. My aim is to create certificate request with XEnroll library in C#. I found working code, so client can create request, but i got certificates with no key- and data-encipherment. I saw, that such requests could be created with CERTENROLLLib, but i have to use XEnroll.

So, how can i do something like this, using XEnroll:

```
// Key Usage Extension 
objExtensionKeyUsage.InitializeEncode(
       X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_KEY_USAGE | 
       X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_NON_REPUDIATION_KEY_USAGE | 
       X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE | 
       X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_DATA_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE
       );
objPkcs10.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)objExtensionKeyUsage);
```

Here is my code:

```
string distNAme = "CN=" +
    userName +
    ",OU=UserUnit" +
    ",O=CRYPTO-PRO" +
    ",L=MOSCOW" +
    ",S=WA" +
    ",C=RU";
string usage = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2";

var enroll = new CEnrollClass();

enroll.ProviderType = 75;
enroll.ProviderName = "Crypto-Pro GOST R 34.10-2001 Cryptographic Service Provider";

string request = enroll.createPKCS10(distNAme, usage);

var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, request);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: okey, the problem has gone with
    enroll.KeySpec = 1;